# How can I delete an apple account?

Tags: apple-id

I have an old account that I don't use. I can log in through

https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/

and edit my account but can't find anywhere to delete it.

Is it possible?

Comment: There is little need to delete accounts.  Just edit the account to remove all your identifying personal and financial information.  Then change the email to some throwaway temporary webmail address.

Answer (score 4):

Any apple account that is created cannot be deleted.  Just create a new account if you need a new one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you couldn't, although I can't find any option to on Apple ID website. You could try this page:

http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/

And/or contact iTunes support, they're the ones who deal with this usually.

Good luck!

Comment: If you can't delete the account, I would change the password for a 30-char or more one. Just to prevent it being hacked in the future and therefore can't cause you any problems. And make sure there is no credit card attached to it, just to be on the safe side. :-)

Comment: You can't delete an account as Apple doesn't provide that functionality as a self-service option.