# How Do I Cancel an Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id

Can I cancel my Apple ID? I  have 3 accounts and I only need one.

Comment: You can’t. Just don’t use it and the Apple ID will be alive, but neglected and lonely for the rest of time

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't cancel these - you can put in a throwaway or secondary email / change the information and stop using the accounts, though.

- [How can I delete an apple account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30565/how-can-i-delete-an-apple-account)
- [How do I delete unwanted Apple ID's?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146673/how-do-i-delete-unwanted-apple-ids)
- [When will Apple delete Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254491/when-will-apple-delete-apple-id)